# Redirect loop when trying to link GitHub profile on Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, jobs

I just signed up for Careers 2.0 and I'm trying to link my GitHub profile. After granting Careers 2.0 access to GitHub, Chrome indicates that there is a redirect loop and I am never able to successfully link my GitHub profile.

I am not sure if [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177804/redirect-loop-with-github) has anything to do with it?